# How come you can 'flip' trigonometric functions?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I am trying to verify

$$\frac{\cot(2x)}{\csc(x)}= \frac{\sin(x)}{\tan(2x)} $$

I noticed that not only has $\frac{\cot(2x)}{\csc(x)}$ been reversed, with $\cot(2x)$ now on the bottom and $\csc(x)$ on top, but in addition to that, the contents of each has also been flipped; making $\cot(2x)$ into $\tan(2x)$. Why can this occur? Can we just freely flip any trig function as we wish? And if we can, why can or can't we do this with constants?

Comment: Are you aware of the definitions of $\cot$ and $\csc$ ?

Comment: $\cot$ is really just an abbreviation for $1/\tan$, and $\csc$ is an abbreviation for $1/\sin$. I've never understood why the Americans insist on teaching them, here we just get by with $\sin$, $\cos$ and $\tan$.

Comment: With constants: $\frac{\frac{1}{3}}{\frac{1}{4}}=\frac{4}{3}$

Comment: @exodu5 Finally someone gets to the heart of the issue. Thanks, that makes a lot of sense! Answer below so I can mark this question as answered

Comment: @chopperdrawlion4 Exodu5 gave you only the example that relates to trigonometry, which might help.  I extended my answer below.  Please check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can 'flip' trigonometric functions by the definition of $\cot$ and $\csc$ as one user already mentioned. Remember that

$$\color{purple}{\sin(x) = \dfrac{1}{\csc(x)}}$$

and

$$\color{green}{\cot(2x) = \dfrac{1}{\tan(2x)}}$$

Altogether, that makes

$$\dfrac{\color{green}{\cot(2x)}}{\color{purple}{\csc(x)}} = \dfrac{\color{purple}{\sin(x)}}{\color{green}{\tan(2x)}}$$

because

$$\dfrac{\color{green}{\cot(2x)}}{\color{purple}{\csc(x)}} = \dfrac{\color{green}{\frac{1}{\tan(2x)}}}{\color{purple}{\frac{1}{\sin(x)}}} \cdot \dfrac{\sin(x)\tan(2x)}{\sin(x)\tan(2x)} = \dfrac{\color{purple}{\sin(x)}}{\color{green}{\tan(2x)}}$$

For any case, we can "flip" the trigonometric expressions to obtain different expressions with the definition of trigonometric identities we know.  No matter the constant/expression inside the trigonometric expression, the trigonometric identity holds.

**Example 1**

$$\begin{aligned}
\cos(\alpha x) = \dfrac{1}{\sec(\alpha x)}
\end{aligned}$$
where $\alpha$ is any nonzero constant.

**Example 2**

$$\begin{aligned}
\cos\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right) = \dfrac{1}{\sec\left(\dfrac{1}{x} \right)}
\end{aligned}$$

where $x$ is nonzero.

**Relationship between this problem and algebra**

If $\cot(2x)$ is some constant $\alpha$ and $\csc(x)$ is some constant $\beta$, then $\tan(2x) = \frac{1}{\alpha}$ and $\sin(x) = \frac{1}{\beta}$ by definitions of $\cot$ and $\csc$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are not zero.  So

$$\dfrac{\cot(2x)}{\csc(x)} = \dfrac{\frac{1}{\tan(2x)}}{\frac{1}{\sin(x)}} = \dfrac{\frac{1}{\alpha}}{\frac{1}{\beta}} = \dfrac{\beta}{\alpha} = \dfrac{\sin(x)}{\tan(2x)}$$

Comment: For completeness, let's recap all of the defintions: $\sec x =1/\cos x$; $\csc x = 1/\sin x$; and $\cot x = 1/\tan x$. And the same relationships are true for all of the hyperbolic counterparts ($\text{sech } x = 1/\cosh x$, etc.).

Comment: That is certainly true for hyperbolic trigonometric expressions and the usual trigonometric expressions.

Comment: I thought cot(x) = cos(x)/sin(x)? I have never seen it in the form cot(x) = 1/tan(x).

Even so, this really doesn't answer the core of my question which is how do you reverse numerator and denominator with trig functions (such as, 1/tan / 1/sin = 1/sin / 1/tan) and how does this relate to constants in normal algebra?

Comment: @chopperdrawlion4 It's true that $\cot(x) = \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}$, but what MPW wants to know is to prove the identity.  First, we recall the identities we know, which are the ones I already provided.  Then, as amWhy showed, you use the identities to derive the right-hand side.

Answer (score 3):

Using the definitions of $\cot$, and $\csc$,

$$\dfrac{\cot (2x)}{\csc x} = \dfrac{\frac 1{\tan(2x)}}{\frac{1}{\sin x}} = \dfrac {\sin x}{\tan(2x)}$$